# PHP/Regex. How to replace all percent (%) chars in url after domain?

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem, i was trying to make a regex for preg_replace to replace all percent (%) chars by "_" char in url after domain name (in domain path).

Example:

```
This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this%is%image.jpg
and 1 url here http://anotherexample.com/t%his%is%image2.jpg
```

Result:

```
This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this_is_image.jpg
and 1 url here http://anotherexample.com/t_his_is_image2.jpg
```

And my question: How to do that using `preg_replace` ?

All what i have is regex for selecting domain in img tag:

`/<img [^>]*src="([^"]+example\.com\/[^"]+)"[^>]*>/`

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Maybe what you really want is [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)?

Comment: regex not required a simple [http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php](str_repalce) will do

Comment: @wogsland, no, i know this function but its important for me to replace it for "_" char.

Comment: @Dagon
yes, but i want to replace % char only in urls - no in other content

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your post to add the information.

Comment: Would you have '%' char in scheme or domain? If not, you can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or you can first use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then do `str_replace` on the path

Comment: @vsnyc - its in domain path. I have a variable with content which also contain domains with % chars. I only need to change all % chars to _ after domain name (in urls)

Comment: since it's not easy to find out if you're selecting an URL in a string with multiple URLs, i would take a simple approach: [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your sentence into an array, checking each word individually. If it's an URL, then use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to filter the %. Then [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) back.

Comment: @KarelG, its a good idea, but too much work for this simple operation. Lets take a look in `/[^"]+example\.com\/([^"]+)/g` - it would select all after domain like when you have http://example.com/content, this regex is selecting only "content". I need only to find way for selecting only percent chars in this content using 1 regex but still inside URL

Comment: @VANKO i didn't knew that the domain could be same. but ins0 solution works. Didn't have thought at that. But for basic user, it's complex ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you dealing with regex replacements i would suggest `preg_replace_callback`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

**Please keep in mind that replaceing `%` in urls can be dangerous as an url can have some valid `%` characters like `http://foo.bar/here%20/index.html` where the `%20` is an whitespace!**

**Example**

```
$haystack = 'This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this%is%image.jpg 
and 1 url here http://anotherexample.com/t%his%is%image2.jpg';

// please use your fav url regex here
$urlRegex = '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#';

$haystack = preg_replace_callback($urlRegex, function($url){
    return str_replace('%', '_', $url[0]);
}, $haystack);
```

Comment: About replacing `%` in urls, its not dangerous when you also replace all whitespaces with other special characters. Also when replacing is just a one-time process to prepare content for using it in the future :) but im gonna keep it in mind

Answer (score 2):

You could match the URLs in the string with a simple regular expression:

```
// $subject is the string    
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/[^\s]+/', $subject, $matches);
```

Then loop over the matches, replace the `%` with `_` in the URL, and replace that in the original `$subject`:

```
foreach ($matches as $match) {
    $search = $match;
    $replace = str_replace('%', '_', $match);
    $subject = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `dirname()`, `basename()` and `str_replace()` like this:

```
$haystack = 'This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this%is%image.jpg';
$result = dirname($haystack) . '/' . str_replace('%','_',basename($haystack));
echo $result;
```

**RESULT:**

```
This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this_is_image.jpg
```

This would be much more efficient than using `preg_replace()` and a regex.

**UPDATE:**

As ins0 points out the above answer depends on the string containing only one url which is at the end.  Not very flexible.  Here's another idea based on what I posted above:

```
$haystack = 'This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this%is%image.jpg 
and 1 url here http://anotherexample.com/t%his%is%image2.jpg';

$parts = explode(' ',$haystack);
foreach ($parts as &$part) {
    if (strpos($part,'http://') !== false || strpos($part,'https://') !== false) {
        $part = dirname($part) . '/'. str_replace('%','_',basename($part));
    }
}
$haystack = implode(' ',$parts);
echo $haystack;
```

**RESULT:**

```
This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this_is_image.jpg
and 1 url here http://anotherexample.com/t_his_is_image2.jpg
```

Comment: i would be surprised if this works with a string which contains multiple URL's (see OP's example).

Comment: the result was "this_is_image.jpg" - but where is "This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e" which was removed from content after execution ;) ?

Comment: @KarelG - Yeah it wouldn't work.  I was assuming each line of his example was a separate string.

Comment: to be hornest, this code uses way more dirty hacks then i can handle

Comment: as @KarelG told, it wouldn't work with multiple urls in string but the basename usage suprised me, im gonna use it in other ways, but still need help in this one

Comment: @ins0 - `basename()` and `dirname()` are specifically designed to extract pieces like this.  I'm not sure why you'd consider this a dirty hack - I actually think it's a pretty clean one liner that gets the job done and uses functions which are well suited to the task.

Comment: @VANKO - If you specifically require a solution to deal with multiple urls in one string it would be good to make that clear in the question.  You don't have to accept my answer but since this is useful and technically answers what you asked, could you at least give me an upvote? :-)

Comment: yes :) but i would be more graceful after you find a way to support multiple urls in 1 string :)

Comment: @billynoah the code only works when the url is at the end of each line, because this fact the code works and ``basename`` and ``dirname`` working as "expected" - otherwise this solution would replace the wrong characters as they are not designed to deal with mixed url strings. I call this a dirty hack, just to get the job done isn't a good answer nor valuable for others.

Comment: @ins0 - yeah you're right about that.  i suppose it works for his examples, but I agree it's not flexible enough to be useful out of context.  Hackiness judgement accepted.

Comment: looks working, im gonna test in and post back result

Answer (score 1):

This is not as elegant as @ins0's answer but I came up with yet another solution, I don't normally code in php, so this may not be the most optimal. Please drop a comment if it can be improved.

```
$str3 = "This is c%ontent with 1 url her%e http://example.com/this%is%image.jpg and 1 url here http://anotherexample.com/t%his%is%image2.jpg ";
$regex = "(http\\S+(\\s|$))";
$unmatched = preg_split($regex, $str3);
preg_match_all($regex, $str3, $matches);
$substituted = (str_replace("%", "_", $matches[0]));
$result = "";
foreach($substituted as $key=>$value) {
    $result .= $unmatched[$key];
    $result .= $substituted[$key];
}  
print $result; # for testing
```